# Why won't all the records show?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using [DataTables](http://datatables.net/index) all is working well, except that all the records don't appear on the output:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
        oTable = $('#permissions').dataTable( {
            //"sScrollY" : "425px", # I added this
            "sAjaxSource": url,
            "bServerSide": true,
            //"sDom": "t",
            "sDom": "frtiS", # I added this
            //"sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "bProcessing" : false, 
            //"aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 2,3 ] }],
            "aoColumnDefs": [ {
              "aTargets": [ 1 ], "sWidth": "30px",
              "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                return format_checkbox('admin', data, full);}
            },{
              "aTargets": [ 2 ], "sWidth": "30px",
              "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                return format_checkbox('consignment', data, full);}
            },{
              "aTargets": [ 3 ], "sWidth": "30px",
              "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                return format_checkbox('team', data, full);}
            },{
              "aTargets": [ 4 ], "sWidth": "30px",
              "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                return format_checkbox('agent', data, full);}
            },{
              "aTargets": [ 5 ], "sWidth": "30px",
              "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                return format_checkbox('report', data, full);}
            },{
              "aTargets": [ 6 ],
              "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                return '<button data-orgid="'+data+'" class="btn btn-danger delbutton">Delete</button>';
              }
            } ],
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "bStateSave": true,            
            "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
                $('.switch').bootstrapSwitch();
                $('.switch').on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
                    var ds = $(data.el)[0].dataset, value = data.value;
                    var ndata = {orgid:ds["orgid"]}
                    ndata[ds["permission"]] = value ? "on" : "off";
                    $.post(post_url, JSON.stringify(ndata)).done(function(data) {
                        oTable.fnStandingRedraw();
                    });                    
                });
                $('#permissions button').click(function(){
                    $.post(del_url, JSON.stringify(this.dataset["orgid"])).done(function(data) {
                        oTable.fnStandingRedraw();
                    });
                });

            }
        });
```

I am relatively new to [DataTables](http://datatables.net/index). This is not my code, as I am just fixing the bug... I cant see why it is not showing all the records? I have played around a bit... I tried changing `bProcessing` to `true`, but it still does not work. Even when I use the scroller, it does not load the last 2 records...

I feel like the answer/solution is simple.
How can I solve this?

Comment: are you including the datatables bootstrap pagination code prior to initializing the datatables object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the default page size is `10`. You can change it by setting the `iDisplayLength` property.

```
oTable = $('#permissions').dataTable( {
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    // rest of your code...
```

If you want to disable pagination completely, which I really do not recommend, you can use this:

```
"bPaginate": false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... `.It does not work.. It now does not display any records...

Comment: @Chirag, I left this "bug" for the evening, with the changes that you suggested here(without the `"bPaginate": false`), When I started up the project now, it displayed all records... Weird right? at least I found it weird... I will accept this answer as @Rory was the first person to give me an answer. @Chirag Thanks for your help... The references you gave helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
 oTable = $('#permissions').dataTable( {
     "iDisplayLength": 50,
     "bPaginate": false
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response... This does not work... if I try to implement it it returns 0 records

Comment: I have update my answer please check and let me know working?

Comment: It still returns 0 records `:|` What could be the problem?

Comment: Please Reffere : https://datatables.net/usage/features and https://datatables.net/usage/options